# Linker Command Failed with exit code 1 Category

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors, objective-c-category, simbl

I am trying to write a SIMBL plugin for Terminal. When attempting to add a category to TTView, I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTView", referenced from:
  l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_TTView_$_MySimplePlugin in MySimplePlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have two classes, TTView and MySimplePlugin in the same files (both interfaces in a .h file and both implementations in a .m file). The interface file has TTView defined as:

```
@interface TTView 
@end
```

and the implementation is where I attempt to add a category to it:

```
@implementation TTView (MySimplePlugin)


@end
```

MySimplePlugin is the name of the file as well as the other class in the file. 
I am not sure where my mistake is.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to #import the .h from the .m?

Comment: @LastMove I checked and the .h file is imported in the .m file. I have an example project side-by-side that is working (PasteWithRightClickForTerminal on GitHub). Everything is the same in my code aside from naming. Is there possibly a flag/setting in Xcode that could cause an error like this to occur? Thanks!